# 2 ng-repeat, 2 <tbody> inside of one table

Tags: html, css, angularjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avaMW.jpg)I have been trying to connect these two tables as one (one next to the other) but after the tbody the second table appears on a new row and below the first table. Could someone provide some guidance as to how to make them appear as one.

```
 <style>
                table, td, th {
                    border: 1px solid black;
                }

                table {
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    width: 50%;

                }

                th {
                    height: 50px;
                }

            </style>
             <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="margin-right: 1px;">ID</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        @*<th>Password</th>We need to delete this but in case of resetting option for admin we leave it for now!*@
                        <th>Fullname</th>
                        <th>Organization</th>
                        <th>Occupation</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        @*<th>Password1</th> We need to delete this but in case of changes we leave it for now!*@
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-repeat="eUser in mList.ListUser" >
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ eUser.ID }}</td>
                        <td>{{ eUser.Username }}</td>
                        @*<td>{{ eUser.Password }}</td> We need to delete this but in case of resetting option for admin we leave it for now! *@
                        <td>{{ eUser.Fullname }}</td>
                        <td>{{ eUser.Organization }}</td>
                        <td>{{ eUser.Occupation }}</td>
                        <td>{{ eUser.Gender }}</td>
                        <td>{{ eUser.Email }}</td>
                        @*<td>{{ eUser.Password1 }}</td>We need to delete this but in case of changes we leave it for now!*@

                    </tr>


                </tbody>
                 <thead>
                     <tr>

                         <th>School Profile</th>
                         <th>DataHub</th>
                         <th>WiderAchieve</th>
                         <th>Enable</th>
                         @*<th>Password1</th> We need to delete this but in case of changes we leave it for now!*@
                     </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody ng-repeat="eRequest in mList.ListRequest">
                     <tr>
                         <td>{{ eRequest.Schoolpro }}</td>
                         <td>{{ eRequest.Widerach }}</td>
                         <td>{{ eRequest.Datahub }}</td>
                         @*<td>{{ eUser.Password1 }}</td>We need to delete this but in case of changes we leave it for now!*@

                         <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="eUser.Enable" disabled /></td>
                         <td>
                             <button type="button" ng-click="doView(eUser)">View</button>
                             <button type="button" ng-click="doEdit(eUser)">Edit</button>
                             <button type="button" ng-click="doDelete(eUser)">Delete</button>
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                     </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thank you[Tables Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7D1F.jpg)

Comment: What's preventing you from using one table with a row instead of a second header?

Comment: You can make this into two different tables. Wrap them both in a div and float both with width of one-half your prescribed width.

Comment: Hello, Oluwafemi Sule and Omri Luzon, thank you for your reply. I did what you said and it helps a lot. I uploaded picture, but the buttons are not inline and comes one above the another. Is it possible to order them in one line? I tried now a couple of ways but they did not work. Thanks!